# Install-PNPSolution is deprecated - what do I do now?

Tags: pnp-powershell, pnp-provision, automation

I have inherited a project portal that provisions project rooms with permissions and site templates. Microsoft have done a change in how contenttypes work so I have updated PNP PowerShell to be able to add contenttypes from the contenttype hub. BUT now I have a new problem, Install-PnPSolution is deprecated. I need to install a wsp to the site, what do I do?

The site template is classic SP. I know that i should rather provision modern sites, but right now I need help with the wsp installation. :)

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint Online :)